# Calculate end date pushing date forward if there is a holiday

Tags: php, mysql

I have written some code where I have a start date and number of days duration and then get an end date ie start date 18th December, duration 21 days, end date 8th January.  However I want to push the end date forward to avoid certain holidays (25th December through to 6th January) so that the end date becomes 15th January.  All the answers I have seen include how to calculate business days and take out weekends, which I don't need.  I just want to be able to define specific holidays in an array, get it to see if the holiday is within the start date and end date and if it is move the end date forward by that number of days.

Oh, then the date needs to be inserted into a database.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You already wrote the answer: "define specific holidays in an array, get it to see if the holiday is within the start date and end date and if it is move the end date forward by that number of days" :-)

Comment: Hi Paul, I've got the holidays in an array called $holidays, no problem but I'm struggling with the code for seeing if that holiday date(s) is between the start date and the end date and if it is pushing it that number of days forward.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in PHP or MySQL? How are the holidays defined in the `$holidays`?

Comment: What data types are you using for start date, end date and the elements of $holidays?

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm trying to achieve this in PHP.  Array is defined as $holidays=array("2015-12-25","2015-12-26","2009-01-01"); but I do want to add more dates.

Comment: Hi Paul, start and end dates are defined as $endDate = strtotime($eng_pend);
    $startDate = strtotime($eng_start);  Thanks

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Comment: //ENGLISH
$eng_level = $_POST["eng_level"];
$eng_start = $_POST["eng_start"];
$eng_duration = $_POST["eng_duration"];

if($eng_level == "E3" || $eng_level == "1" || $eng_level == "2")
{
 $eng_aim = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+4 Day", $journey_start));
 $eng_pstart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($eng_start));
        $eng_pin = strtotime($eng_pstart);
        $eng_dur = $eng_duration * 7;
        $eng_pend = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$eng_dur." Day", $eng_pin));

Comment: //The function returns the no. days between two dates and it adds the holiday dates
function getDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays){
    // do strtotime calculations just once
    $endDate = strtotime($eng_pend);
    $startDate = strtotime($eng_pstart);

    $holidays=array("2015-12-25","2015-12-26","2009-01-01");

    //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
    //We add one to inlude both dates in the interval.
    $daysx = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

Comment: //We add the holidays
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);
        
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate)
            $daysx++;
    }
    return $eng_dur_days;
    
    $eng_pendx = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$eng_dur_days." Day", $start_date));

Comment: $eng_sql = "INSERT INTO learner_plan (learner_id, centre_id, staff_id, learner_plan_set, learner_plan_subject, learner_plan_level, learner_plan_aim, learner_plan_pstart, learner_plan_pend) VALUES('$id', '".$centre["centre_id"]."','".$staff["staff_id"]."', '0', 'English Functional Skills', '$eng_level', '".$eng_aim."', '".$eng_pstart."', '".$eng_pendx."')";
 mysql_query($eng_sql) or die(header("location:qualfix.php?id=$id&status=$status&error=inserr"));
}

Comment: $eng_pendx is returning 30/11/-0001 from the database

Comment: You should not write multiline code in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the $holidays array. If a holiday is in the given range, then move end date one day in the future:

```php
$startDate = new DateTime('2015-12-18');
$endDate   = new DateTime('2016-01-08');
// $holidays array must be sorted. if not, then sort it first
$holidays = array("2015-12-25","2015-12-26","2016-01-01");

$newEndDate = $endDate;

foreach ($holidays as $holiday) {
    $holidayDate = new DateTime($holiday);
    if ($startDate <= $holidayDate && $holidayDate <= $newEndDate) {
        // there is a holiday in the range
        $newEndDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}

echo($newEndDate->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've popped the code in but when it runs I get a blank screen (I read another post that said this was to do with var_dump).  So if $newEndDate is adding dates to the end, how do I get the new end date to show in the mysql query?

Comment: Use `$newEndDate->format('Y-m-d')` to get the string representation for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all those that posted possible solutions.  I solved the problem by adding a selector to the php page which adds 7, 14 or 21 days to the end date (the user sees this as 1 week, 2 weeks etc) and this solved the problem.

Comment: This is a comment, and not an answer.